# PyQt QFileEditor default suffix

Tags: pyqt, pyside

I have looked out through bunch of code but this peace of code doesn't work as expected for me:

```
export_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
export_dialog.setWindowTitle('Export')
export_dialog.setDirectory(EXPORT_DIR)
export_dialog.setAcceptMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
export_dialog.setNameFilter('INI files (*.ini)')
export_dialog.setDefaultSuffix('ini')
export_file, _ = export_dialog.getSaveFileName()
print(export_file)
```

I'm saving my file without extension, counting on that my above configurations will set it properly, but it doesn't work. There is no extension added.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is the second question you've asked that makes the same basic mistake. You're attempting to use `getOpenFileName`, `getSaveFileName`, etc as **instance methods**, when they are in fact **static methods** on the QFileDialog class. Because of this, all the changes you make to `export_dialog` in your example will *have no effect whatsoever*, because `getSaveFileName` will always create its own internal file dialog. You will have to call `export_dialog.show()` or `export_dialog.exec_()` to open the file dialog you created yourself.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. Wonderful way to start a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
export_dialog.setWindowTitle('Export')
export_dialog.setDirectory(EXPORT_DIR)
export_dialog.setAcceptMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
export_dialog.setNameFilter('INI files (*.ini)')
export_dialog.setDefaultSuffix('ini')
if export_dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QFileDialog.Accepted:
    print(export_dialog.selectedFiles()[0])
```

This code will return a full file path with selected filter also.